# Quad Tree and Collision Detection Implementation

Tags: java, game, tree, collision, physics

I have an implementation of a quad tree and abstract collision detection classes. The code works but looks very ugly, but I don't know what I could change to make it better.

The reason I used two interfaces instead of just extending an abstract class is because the classes which will use this are render objects and have to extend `RenderObject`. This is a thing I don't want to change because `RenderObject` doesn't have to be a collision instance every time.

The Quad Tree:

```
package de.skysoldier.headsoccer.physics2d;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.ListIterator;

import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector2f;

import de.skysoldier.headsoccer.CollisionInstance;

public class QuadTree {

    public static final int MAX_DEPTH = 4;
    public static final int MIN_ITEMS = 2;
    public static final int MAX_ITEMS = 10;

    private int depth;
    private int objectCount;
    private Vector2f minCorner;
    private Vector2f maxCorner;
    private Vector2f center;
    private QuadTree parent;
    private ArrayList<QuadTree> children;
    private ArrayList<CollisionInstance> collisionInstanceList;

    public QuadTree(Vector2f minCorner, Vector2f maxCorner){
        this(0, minCorner, maxCorner, null); 
    }

    public QuadTree(int depth, Vector2f minCorner, Vector2f maxCorner, QuadTree parent){
        this.minCorner = minCorner;
        this.maxCorner = maxCorner;
        this.center = new Vector2f(minCorner.x + 0.5f * (maxCorner.x - minCorner.x), minCorner.y + 0.5f * (maxCorner.y - minCorner.y));
        this.depth = depth;
        this.parent = parent;
        collisionInstanceList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public QuadTree(int depth, float minx, float miny, float maxx, float maxy, QuadTree parent){
        this(depth, new Vector2f(minx, miny), new Vector2f(maxx, maxy), parent);
    }

    private int getQuadrandIndex(CollisionInstance collisionInstance){
        AABB aabb = collisionInstance.getCollideable().getAabb();
        int quadrandPositionX = aabb.getMinCorner().x > center.x ? 1 : (aabb.getMaxCorner().x < center.x ? 0 : -1); //1: right | 0: left
        int quadrandPositionY = aabb.getMinCorner().y > center.y ? 1 : (aabb.getMaxCorner().y < center.y ? 0 : -1); //1: top | 0: bottom
        return quadrandPositionX < 0 || quadrandPositionY < 0 ? -1 : 2 * quadrandPositionX + quadrandPositionY;
    }

    public void add(CollisionInstance CollisionInstance){
        objectCount++;
        if(objectCount > MAX_ITEMS && !hasChildren() && depth < MAX_DEPTH) createChildren();
        int quadrandIndex = -1;
        if(hasChildren() && (quadrandIndex = getQuadrandIndex(CollisionInstance)) >= 0){
            children.get(quadrandIndex).add(CollisionInstance);
        }
        else collisionInstanceList.add(CollisionInstance);

    }

    public void remove(CollisionInstance CollisionInstance){
        objectCount--;
        if(objectCount < MIN_ITEMS && hasChildren()) releaseChildren();
        int quadrandIndex = -1;
        if(hasChildren() && (quadrandIndex = getQuadrandIndex(CollisionInstance)) >= 0){
            children.get(quadrandIndex).remove(CollisionInstance);
        }
        else collisionInstanceList.remove(CollisionInstance);
    }

    public boolean hasChildren(){
        return children != null;
    }

    private void createChildren(){
        children = new ArrayList<>();
        children.add(new QuadTree(depth + 1, minCorner.x, minCorner.y, center.x, center.y, this)); //bottom left
        children.add(new QuadTree(depth + 1, minCorner.x, center.y, center.x, maxCorner.y, this)); //top left
        children.add(new QuadTree(depth + 1, center.x, minCorner.y, maxCorner.x, center.y, this)); //bottom right
        children.add(new QuadTree(depth + 1, center.x, center.y, maxCorner.x, maxCorner.y, this)); //top right
        ArrayList<CollisionInstance> collisionInstanceCopys = new ArrayList<>();
        collisionInstanceCopys.addAll(collisionInstanceList);
        collisionInstanceList.clear();
        objectCount -= collisionInstanceCopys.size();
        Iterator<CollisionInstance> iterator = collisionInstanceCopys.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            add(iterator.next());
        }
    }

    private void releaseChildren(){
        collisionInstanceList.addAll(collectCollisionInstances(false));
        children = null;
    }

    public String toString(){
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append(tabString(depth, "[QT depth: " + depth + ", num: " + objectCount + "] " + collisionInstanceList));
        builder.append("\n");
        if(hasChildren()){
            for(QuadTree qt : children) builder.append(qt);
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }

    public Vector2f getMinCorner(){
        return minCorner;
    }

    public Vector2f getMaxCorner(){
        return maxCorner;
    }

    public static String tabString(int depth, String appendix){
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i < depth; i++) builder.append("  ");
        if(appendix != null) builder.append(appendix);
        return builder.toString();
    }

    public QuadTree getParent(){
        return parent;
    }

    private ArrayList<CollisionInstance> getPossibleCollisions(ArrayList<CollisionInstance> collisions){
        ArrayList<CollisionInstance> subList = collectCollisionInstances(false);
        ListIterator<CollisionInstance> iterator1 = collisionInstanceList.listIterator();
        while(iterator1.hasNext()){
            CollisionInstance collisionInstance1 = iterator1.next();
            ListIterator<CollisionInstance> iterator2 = collisionInstanceList.listIterator(iterator1.nextIndex());
            while(iterator2.hasNext()){
                collisions.add(collisionInstance1);
                collisions.add(iterator2.next());
            }
            for(CollisionInstance collisionInstance2 : subList){
                collisions.add(collisionInstance1);
                collisions.add(collisionInstance2);
            }
        }
        if(hasChildren()){
            for(QuadTree tree : children){
                tree.getPossibleCollisions(collisions);
            }
        }
        return collisions;
    }

    public ArrayList<CollisionInstance> getPossibleCollisions(){
        ArrayList<CollisionInstance> collisions = new ArrayList<>();
        getPossibleCollisions(collisions);
        return collisions;
    }

    private ArrayList<CollisionInstance> collectCollisionInstances(boolean addSelf){
        ArrayList<CollisionInstance> collisionInstances = new ArrayList<>();
        collectCollisionInstances(addSelf, collisionInstances);
        return collisionInstances;
    }

    private void collectCollisionInstances(boolean addSelf, ArrayList<CollisionInstance> collisionInstances){
        if(addSelf) collisionInstances.addAll(collisionInstanceList);
        if(hasChildren()){
            for(QuadTree tree : children){
                tree.collectCollisionInstances(true, collisionInstances);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The AABB class:

```
package de.skysoldier.headsoccer.physics2d;

import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector2f;
import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector3f;

public class AABB {

    private Vector3f minCorner;
    private Vector3f maxCorner;
    private Vector3f center;

    public AABB(){
        this(new Vector3f(), new Vector3f());
    }

    public AABB(Vector2f minCorner, Vector2f maxCorner){
        this(new Vector3f(minCorner.x, minCorner.y, 0), new Vector3f(maxCorner.x, maxCorner.y, 0));
    }

    public AABB(Vector3f minCorner, Vector3f maxCorner){
        this.minCorner = minCorner;
        this.maxCorner = maxCorner;
        calcCenter();
    }

    public void calcCenter(){
        center = new Vector3f(
            minCorner.x + 0.5f * (maxCorner.x - minCorner.x), 
            minCorner.y + 0.5f * (maxCorner.y - minCorner.y), 
            minCorner.z + 0.5f * (maxCorner.z - minCorner.z));
    }

    public Vector3f getMinCorner(){
        return minCorner;
    }

    public Vector3f getMaxCorner(){
        return maxCorner;
    }

    public Vector3f getCenter(){
        return center;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "[AABB: min(" + minCorner.x + "|" + minCorner.y + "), ctr(" + center.x + "|" + center.y + "), max(" + maxCorner.x + "|" + maxCorner.y + ")]";
    }
}
```

Collision Instance:

```
package de.skysoldier.headsoccer;

import de.skysoldier.headsoccer.physics2d.Collideable;
import de.skysoldier.headsoccer.physics2d.CollisionListener;

public interface CollisionInstance {
    Collideable getCollideable();
    CollisionListener getCollisionListener();
}
```

Collideable:

```
package de.skysoldier.headsoccer.physics2d;

import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector3f;

public interface Collideable {
    AABB getAabb();
    boolean basicCollision(Collideable collideable);
    boolean collision(Collideable collideable);
    boolean contains(Vector3f point);
}
```

Abstract implementation of collideable:

```
package de.skysoldier.headsoccer.physics2d;

public abstract class AbstractCollideable implements Collideable {

    private AABB aabb;

    public AbstractCollideable(AABB aabb){
        this.aabb = aabb;
    }

    public AABB getAabb(){
        return aabb;
    }

    public boolean basicCollision(Collideable collideable){
        AABB aabb1 = getAabb();
        AABB aabb2 = collideable.getAabb();
        return !(aabb2.getMinCorner().y > aabb1.getMaxCorner().y || aabb2.getMaxCorner().y < aabb1.getMinCorner().y || aabb2.getMaxCorner().x < aabb1.getMinCorner().x || aabb2.getMinCorner().x > aabb1.getMaxCorner().x);
    }

    public abstract boolean collision(Collideable collisionInstance);
}
```

cubical collideable:

```
package de.skysoldier.headsoccer.physics2d;

import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector3f;

public class CubicalCollideable extends AbstractCollideable {

    public CubicalCollideable(AABB aabb){
        super(aabb);
    }

    public boolean collision(Collideable collideable){
        if(collideable instanceof CircularCollideable) return collideable.collision(this);
        return basicCollision(collideable);
    }

    public boolean contains(Vector3f point){
        AABB aabb = getAabb();
        return point.x >= aabb.getMinCorner().x && point.x <= aabb.getMaxCorner().x && point.y >= aabb.getMinCorner().y && point.y <= aabb.getMaxCorner().y;
    }
}
```

circular collideable:

```
package de.skysoldier.headsoccer.physics2d;

import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector3f;

public class CircularCollideable extends AbstractCollideable {

    private float radius;

    public CircularCollideable(float radius){
        super(new AABB(new Vector3f(), new Vector3f()));
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public float getRadius(){
        return radius;
    }

    public boolean collision(Collideable collideable){
        if(collideable instanceof CircularCollideable){
            Vector3f center2 = collideable.getAabb().getCenter();
            Vector3f center1 = getAabb().getCenter();
            float a = Math.abs(center2.x - center1.x);
            float b = Math.abs(center2.y - center1.y);
            float maxDistance = getRadius() + ((CircularCollideable) collideable).getRadius();
            return a * a + b * b < maxDistance * maxDistance;
        }
        else if(collideable instanceof CubicalCollideable){
            CubicalCollideable cubical = (CubicalCollideable) collideable;
            if(cubical.basicCollision(this)){
                return true;
            }
            else {
                Vector3f v1 = cubical.getAabb().getMinCorner();
                Vector3f v2 = cubical.getAabb().getMaxCorner();
                Vector3f v3 = new Vector3f(v1.x, v2.y, 0);
                Vector3f v4 = new Vector3f(v1.y, v2.x, 0);
                float radiusSquared = radius * radius;
                return distanceSquared(v1) <= radiusSquared || 
                       distanceSquared(v2) <= radiusSquared ||
                       distanceSquared(v3) <= radiusSquared ||
                       distanceSquared(v4) <= radiusSquared;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public float distanceSquared(Vector3f point){
        float dx = Math.abs(point.x - getAabb().getCenter().x);
        float dy = Math.abs(point.y - getAabb().getCenter().y);
        return dx * dx + dy * dy;
    }

    public boolean contains(Vector3f point){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Example usage class:

```
class TestObject extends AGLRenderObject implements CollisionInstance, CollisionListener {

        private Collideable collideable;

        public TestObject(){
            //super constructor and stuff
            //collideable = ...;
        }

        @Override
        public void collisionResponse(CollisionInstance collisionInstance){
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public Collideable getCollideable(){
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return collideable;
        }

        @Override
        public CollisionListener getCollisionListener(){
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return this;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest the following changes to make the code more readable:

### Avoid long expressions in return statements

E.g., instead of this:
`return !(aabb2.getMinCorner().y > aabb1.getMaxCorner().y || aabb2.getMaxCorner().y < aabb1.getMinCorner().y || aabb2.getMaxCorner().x < aabb1.getMinCorner().x || aabb2.getMinCorner().x > aabb1.getMaxCorner().x);`

You could write something like this:

```
boolean outsideY1 = aabb2.getMinCorner().y > aabb1.getMaxCorner().y;
boolean outsideY2 = aabb2.getMaxCorner().y < aabb1.getMinCorner().y;
boolean outsideX1 = aabb2.getMaxCorner().x < aabb1.getMinCorner().x;
boolean outsideX2 = aabb2.getMinCorner().x > aabb1.getMaxCorner().x;
return !(outsideY1 || outsideY2 || outsideX1 || outsideX2);
```

Note, that by choosing descriptive names (I'm not sure if I got the intent right, feel free to change them), the code becomes easier to understand. Besides, it is also easier to debug: you can see which component returns true/false.
There are another few places, where return expression could be split up in a similar way.

### Capitalizing

Follow the Java conventions, and start variable names with small letter, instead of capital letter. E.g. change this:
`public void add(CollisionInstance CollisionInstance)`
to this:
`public void add(CollisionInstance collisionInstance)`

### Single return point in functions

E.g. in CircularCollideable.collision, you could store the return value in a variable, and return it at the end of the function, instead of having more return points, i.e. something like this:

```
public boolean collision(Collideable collideable){
    boolean ret = false;
    if(collideable instanceof CircularCollideable){
        // ... snip
        ret = a * a + b * b < maxDistance * maxDistance;
    }
    else if(collideable instanceof CubicalCollideable){
        CubicalCollideable cubical = (CubicalCollideable) collideable;
        if(cubical.basicCollision(this)){
            ret = true;
        }
        else {
            // ... snip
            // also consider splitting the expression :)
            ret = distanceSquared(v1) <= radiusSquared || 
                   distanceSquared(v2) <= radiusSquared ||
                   distanceSquared(v3) <= radiusSquared ||
                   distanceSquared(v4) <= radiusSquared;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

While there are varying opinions, on whether single return point is a good pattern or not (see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36707/should-a-function-have-only-one-return-statement)), in your case, it would be a good choice, since the function is already split up into more if/else branches.
The advantage of this change is, that it makes the code easier to debug (you can set one single break point, and check the return value there).

On a side note: you might want to refactor your code in a way, that large if/else constructs with instanceof's are avoided (especially if you will have many types of collideables). While I can't suggest any better example, you could have a look at the [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) for a starting point.

### Make methods private

I'm referring to `CircularCollideable.distanceSquared()`. This method is only used within its class, so it would be better to make it private. This also helps a lot in understandability of the code, especially if you are developing with an IDE, that will visually mark private/public methods in a different way.

Comment: thank you for this useful improvement suggestions. I'll try to clean up the code, and take care of this things